# Someone can help to verify smart contract on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, ropsten, contract-verification

Here is source code of this smart contract !
http://dweb.link/ipfs/QmNxz54r9DfNqqgm9h7oJp52QgTPesbnGQ4PpppkSBjwH8

Complier version : 0.5.16
What I tried: Deployed successfully but can not verify on Etherscan with Ropsten test net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a CLI that may help you, called [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol). You can install it via Homebrew if you're on Mac, or [download](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol/releases) one of the executables I provide if you're on Windows or Linux:

```sh
$ brew tap paulrberg/multisol
$ brew install multisol
```

Then you can use it like this:

```sh
$ multisol path/to/YourContract.sol
```

This will generate a folder named "multisol-yourcontract" that can be used to verify the source code on Etherscan for a deployed instance of `YourContract.sol`. Note that the type of verification is "Solidity (Multi-Part files)".

Answer (score 1):

I removed all the instance of solidity complier specifications and just added one on top as majority wanted this version exactly. Also when you copypaste your code and it is compiling correctly on remix but you see incorrect abi constructor arguments while verifying and publishing just delete those and select publish. Here you contract is published on ropsten https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x27e0a291abf1b36f12db466a5d37875919ca1c1b#code

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2021-03-17
*/

// File: contracts/interfaces/IPancakePair.sol

//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity =0.5.16;

interface IPancakePair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;

    function initialize(address, address) external;
}

// File: contracts/interfaces/IPancakeERC20.sol



interface IPancakeERC20 {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;
}

// File: contracts/libraries/SafeMath.sol



// a library for performing overflow-safe math, courtesy of DappHub (https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math)

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require((z = x + y) >= x, 'ds-math-add-overflow');
    }

    function sub(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require((z = x - y) <= x, 'ds-math-sub-underflow');
    }

    function mul(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x, 'ds-math-mul-overflow');
    }
}

// File: contracts/PancakeERC20.sol





contract PancakeERC20 is IPancakeERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public constant name = 'Pancake LPs';
    string public constant symbol = 'Cake-LP';
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint  public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;

    bytes32 public DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    // keccak256("Permit(address owner,address spender,uint256 value,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)");
    bytes32 public constant PERMIT_TYPEHASH = 0x6e71edae12b1b97f4d1f60370fef10105fa2faae0126114a169c64845d6126c9;
    mapping(address => uint) public nonces;

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    constructor() public {
        uint chainId;
        assembly {
            chainId := chainid
        }
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
                keccak256(bytes(name)),
                keccak256(bytes('1')),
                chainId,
                address(this)
            )
        );
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint value) internal {
        totalSupply = totalSupply.add(value);
        balanceOf[to] = balanceOf[to].add(value);
        emit Transfer(address(0), to, value);
    }

    function _burn(address from, uint value) internal {
        balanceOf[from] = balanceOf[from].sub(value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(value);
        emit Transfer(from, address(0), value);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint value) private {
        allowance[owner][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint value) private {
        balanceOf[from] = balanceOf[from].sub(value);
        balanceOf[to] = balanceOf[to].add(value);
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        if (allowance[from][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
            allowance[from][msg.sender] = allowance[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
        }
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external {
        require(deadline >= block.timestamp, 'Pancake: EXPIRED');
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                '\x19\x01',
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
                keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, owner, spender, value, nonces[owner]++, deadline))
            )
        );
        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(recoveredAddress != address(0) && recoveredAddress == owner, 'Pancake: INVALID_SIGNATURE');
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
    }
}

// File: contracts/libraries/Math.sol



// a library for performing various math operations

library Math {
    function min(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        z = x < y ? x : y;
    }

    // babylonian method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)
    function sqrt(uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        if (y > 3) {
            z = y;
            uint x = y / 2 + 1;
            while (x < z) {
                z = x;
                x = (y / x + x) / 2;
            }
        } else if (y != 0) {
            z = 1;
        }
    }
}

// File: contracts/libraries/UQ112x112.sol


// a library for handling binary fixed point numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format))

// range: [0, 2**112 - 1]
// resolution: 1 / 2**112

library UQ112x112 {
    uint224 constant Q112 = 2**112;

    // encode a uint112 as a UQ112x112
    function encode(uint112 y) internal pure returns (uint224 z) {
        z = uint224(y) * Q112; // never overflows
    }

    // divide a UQ112x112 by a uint112, returning a UQ112x112
    function uqdiv(uint224 x, uint112 y) internal pure returns (uint224 z) {
        z = x / uint224(y);
    }
}

// File: contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol



interface IERC20 {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

// File: contracts/interfaces/IPancakeFactory.sol



interface IPancakeFactory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

    function feeTo() external view returns (address);
    function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function setFeeTo(address) external;
    function setFeeToSetter(address) external;
}

// File: contracts/interfaces/IPancakeCallee.sol



interface IPancakeCallee {
    function pancakeCall(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data) external;
}

// File: contracts/PancakePair.sol


contract PancakePair is IPancakePair, PancakeERC20 {
    using SafeMath  for uint;
    using UQ112x112 for uint224;

    uint public constant MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY = 10**3;
    bytes4 private constant SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));

    address public factory;
    address public token0;
    address public token1;

    uint112 private reserve0;           // uses single storage slot, accessible via getReserves
    uint112 private reserve1;           // uses single storage slot, accessible via getReserves
    uint32  private blockTimestampLast; // uses single storage slot, accessible via getReserves

    uint public price0CumulativeLast;
    uint public price1CumulativeLast;
    uint public kLast; // reserve0 * reserve1, as of immediately after the most recent liquidity event

    uint private unlocked = 1;
    modifier lock() {
        require(unlocked == 1, 'Pancake: LOCKED');
        unlocked = 0;
        _;
        unlocked = 1;
    }

    function getReserves() public view returns (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1, uint32 _blockTimestampLast) {
        _reserve0 = reserve0;
        _reserve1 = reserve1;
        _blockTimestampLast = blockTimestampLast;
    }

    function _safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) private {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED');
    }

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    constructor() public {
        factory = msg.sender;
    }

    // called once by the factory at time of deployment
    function initialize(address _token0, address _token1) external {
        require(msg.sender == factory, 'Pancake: FORBIDDEN'); // sufficient check
        token0 = _token0;
        token1 = _token1;
    }

    // update reserves and, on the first call per block, price accumulators
    function _update(uint balance0, uint balance1, uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1) private {
        require(balance0 <= uint112(-1) && balance1 <= uint112(-1), 'Pancake: OVERFLOW');
        uint32 blockTimestamp = uint32(block.timestamp % 2**32);
        uint32 timeElapsed = blockTimestamp - blockTimestampLast; // overflow is desired
        if (timeElapsed > 0 && _reserve0 != 0 && _reserve1 != 0) {
            // * never overflows, and + overflow is desired
            price0CumulativeLast += uint(UQ112x112.encode(_reserve1).uqdiv(_reserve0)) * timeElapsed;
            price1CumulativeLast += uint(UQ112x112.encode(_reserve0).uqdiv(_reserve1)) * timeElapsed;
        }
        reserve0 = uint112(balance0);
        reserve1 = uint112(balance1);
        blockTimestampLast = blockTimestamp;
        emit Sync(reserve0, reserve1);
    }

    // if fee is on, mint liquidity equivalent to 1/6th of the growth in sqrt(k)
    function _mintFee(uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1) private returns (bool feeOn) {
        address feeTo = IPancakeFactory(factory).feeTo();
        feeOn = feeTo != address(0);
        uint _kLast = kLast; // gas savings
        if (feeOn) {
            if (_kLast != 0) {
                uint rootK = Math.sqrt(uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1));
                uint rootKLast = Math.sqrt(_kLast);
                if (rootK > rootKLast) {
                    uint numerator = totalSupply.mul(rootK.sub(rootKLast));
                    uint denominator = rootK.mul(3).add(rootKLast);
                    uint liquidity = numerator / denominator;
                    if (liquidity > 0) _mint(feeTo, liquidity);
                }
            }
        } else if (_kLast != 0) {
            kLast = 0;
        }
    }

    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function mint(address to) external lock returns (uint liquidity) {
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint amount0 = balance0.sub(_reserve0);
        uint amount1 = balance1.sub(_reserve1);

        bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
        uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
        if (_totalSupply == 0) {
            liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);
           _mint(address(0), MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY); // permanently lock the first MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY tokens
        } else {
            liquidity = Math.min(amount0.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve0, amount1.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve1);
        }
        require(liquidity > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED');
        _mint(to, liquidity);

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
        emit Mint(msg.sender, amount0, amount1);
    }

    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function burn(address to) external lock returns (uint amount0, uint amount1) {
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        address _token0 = token0;                                // gas savings
        address _token1 = token1;                                // gas savings
        uint balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)];

        bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
        uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
        amount0 = liquidity.mul(balance0) / _totalSupply; // using balances ensures pro-rata distribution
        amount1 = liquidity.mul(balance1) / _totalSupply; // using balances ensures pro-rata distribution
        require(amount0 > 0 && amount1 > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_BURNED');
        _burn(address(this), liquidity);
        _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0);
        _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1);
        balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
        emit Burn(msg.sender, amount0, amount1, to);
    }

    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
        require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

        uint balance0;
        uint balance1;
        { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
        address _token0 = token0;
        address _token1 = token1;
        require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'Pancake: INVALID_TO');
        if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (data.length > 0) IPancakeCallee(to).pancakeCall(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
        balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        }
        uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
        uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
        require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
        uint balance0Adjusted = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(2));
        uint balance1Adjusted = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(2));
        require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(1000**2), 'Pancake: K');
        }

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
    }

    // force balances to match reserves
    function skim(address to) external lock {
        address _token0 = token0; // gas savings
        address _token1 = token1; // gas savings
        _safeTransfer(_token0, to, IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this)).sub(reserve0));
        _safeTransfer(_token1, to, IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this)).sub(reserve1));
    }

    // force reserves to match balances
    function sync() external lock {
        _update(IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this)), IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this)), reserve0, reserve1);
    }
}
```